# Can I Declare and initialize multiple variables in one line with a tuple?

Tags: swift, variables, initialization, tuples, declaration

I have a function that returns a tuple of 3 UIImages.

```
private func getImagesFrom(_ arr:[String]) -> (UIImage, UIImage, UIImage) {
    return (UIImage(named: arr[0]), UIImage(named: arr[1]), UIImage(named: arr[2])
}
```

Is it possible to declare and initialize 3 variables from the result of this function like

```
(var imageOne, var imageTwo, var imageThree) = getImagesFrom(["img1", "img2", "img3"])
```

I know the above line doesn't compile, but is there some syntax that will allow this functionality?

Comment: `let (imageOne, imageTwo, imageThree) = getImages...`

Comment: Please, folks, [RTFD](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID329) (**R**ead **T**he **F**antastic **D**ocumentation)

Comment: well, excuuUUUuuuse me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func getImagesTuple(from array: Array<String>) -> (UIImage, UIImage, UIImage) {
  (UIImage(named: array[0])!, UIImage(named: array[1])!, UIImage(named: array[2])!)
}

let (imageOne, imageTwo, imageThree) = getImagesTuple(from: ["imageOne", "imageTwo", "imageThree"])
```